# Value in shared memory different after shared memory access C++

Tags: c++, shared-memory

I am trying to create shared memory, but whenever I access it from a child process its value is different than what it should be. I think that I am using shmget() correctly. I have tried a lot of stuff that I have found online, but I can't find anyone with the same problem I am having. No matter what I enter num as, whenever I try to get l->returnLicense it outputs 0. I'm really at a loss as to what to try next.

```cpp
#include "license.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int validateArguments (int num) {
    if (num == -69) {
        //no arg
        return 10;
    }   
    if (num < 1 || num > 20) {
        //warning use 20 as num
        return 10;
    }
    return num;
}

int initSharedMemory (License *l) {
    key_t key = ftok("/tmp", 'J');
        cout << "key: " << key << endl;
    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(l), 0666|IPC_CREAT);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("Shared memory");
        return -1;
    }
    l = (License*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
    if (l == (void*) -1) {
        perror("Shared memory attach");
        return -1;
    }
    return shmid;
}

void detachSharedMemory (License *l) {
    shmdt(l);
}

void destroySharedMemory (int shmid) {
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}

void spawn (int shmid) {
    pid_t c_pid = fork();
    if (c_pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
    } else if (c_pid > 0) {
        cout << "parent" << shmid << endl;
        c_pid = wait(NULL);
    } else {
        cout << "child" << endl;
        License *l;
        key_t key = ftok("/tmp", 'J');
        cout << "key: " << key << endl;
        int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(l), 0666);
        cout << shmid;
        l = (License*) shmat(shmid,0,0);
        if(l == (void*) -1) {
            perror("memory attach");
            exit(0);
        }
        int num = l->returnLicense();
        cout << num << "num\n";
        shmdt(l);
        char* args[] = {"./testChild", NULL};
        execvp(args[0],args);
        exit(0);
    }
}

int main (int argv, char *argc[]) {
    int num;
    if (argv == 2) {
        num = atoi(argc[1]);
    } else {
        num = -69;
    }
    num = validateArguments (num);
    License *l;
    int shmid = initSharedMemory (l);
    License *tmp = l;
    tmp->initLicense(num);
    spawn(shmid);
    cout << l->returnLicense() << endl;
    detachSharedMemory(l);
    destroySharedMemory(shmid); 

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not including the entirety of my code, but I think this is enough to illustrate my problem. I copied code from the testChild that I exec from this process so that you can see the problem I'm facing all in one file.

Comment: [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)` makes a good chunk of this code go away.

Comment: @sweenish: How?  `shared_ptr` is not designed for sharing across processes!

Comment: James, your `License *l` is uninitialized.  Copying it to `tmp` is undefined behavior.  Calling `tmp->initLicense(num)` is undefined behavior.  Calling `l->returnLicense()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I only added that tmp for testing, forgot to remove it. The calls work though, I get the correct output when I call l->returnLicense()

Comment: That's what I get for glancing, I guess.

Comment: Are those `posix` APIs? Maybe a proper tag could improve your chances to get a good answer. Ehm, since this is tagged as `c++`, consider to take advantage of it (RAIII).

Comment: The only time l->returnLicense does not return the correct value is when I try to access the shared memory segment.

Comment: @James: You aren't trying to access the shared memory segment.  The only pointer you have to shared memory is inside `initSharedMemory` and then it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 4):

```
License *l;  // uninitialized
int shmid = initSharedMemory (l);  // pass l by value, UB!
License *tmp = l;  // copy uninitialized pointer, UB!
tmp->initLicense(num);  // call member function through uninitialized pointer, BOOM!
spawn(shmid);
cout << l->returnLicense() << endl;  // call member function through uninitialized pointer, BOOM!
```

Probably you meant for your `initSharedMemory()` function to have a reference-typed parameter, so that it would affect the `License * l;` variable in `main()`.

Comment: SOLVED. It's always something that seems incredibly simple after you realize. Thank you!